# Only run query for TableB if TableA is not empty

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I have a script which deletes the data from TableB and inserts data from TableA to TableB .

How can I perform a `DELETE * from TABLE B` query just when there is ANY data in TableA?

Comment: Short answer? Yes.

Comment: where is script you have written ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```
DELETE FROM table_b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_a)
```